# Simple form POST from HTML to ASP.NET page fails

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

Ultimately I have to send form post data from an iPad app to a simple ASP.NET page. Before I do that I just want to get the basic ASP.NET page working by sending a simple form post from an HTML page I have directly to the asp.net page. I post the html form to the asp.net page, and the Request.Form object is always null. I know the page is being hit, because the debugger stops on my breakpoints in the codebehind (.cs).

I know that if I sent the form post from the .aspx page it would work; that's the traditional asp.net form post model. But if the page won't process a post from an arbitrary html page then I believe it will also fail when the post comes from the ipad.

This is puzzling to me. Does ASP.NET somehow discriminate on form posts? Does it somehow know that the post didn't originate from its own aspx, and ignore the post? What is going on and how do I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the aspx page need to render a display?  If not and it only needs to process the POSTed payload, you might want to consider creating an HttpHandler.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.processrequest.aspx for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, ASP.NET does discriminate on form POSTs. If you set up an ASP.NET form normally and then use a tool such as Fiddler to see exactly what is being posted, then you will see all the hidden fields and values that ASP.NET requires for that page. Then, you'll be ready to send data from a non-ASP.NET source.

Comment: Is there no other way? Maybe an HTTP Handler in .NET could grab the raw form post somehow? Would love an idea on this.